# How to make labels and title bold in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, bold

I want to make the labels and title of the plot bold. I know how to change size, i.e.

> set title font ',30'

I looked at a question here which state to do this:

> set ytics format "{/:Bold {/=14 %h}}"

But it works only for tics. How to do it for labels and titles also?

Comment: Which gnuplot version and which terminal are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which gnuplot version and which terminal are you using? The following should work from gnuplot >=5.0.0 with wxt terminal.

**Code:**

```
### bold labels and title
reset
set term wxt enhanced

set title  "{/:Bold My Title in bold}"
set xlabel "{/:Bold my xlabel in bold}"
set ylabel "{/:Bold my ylabel in bold}"

plot x
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: What about the key?

Comment: @Sahil  right. For some reason in 5.4.1 the key seems to be bold automatically, but not in 5.0.0, so then try `set key font "{:Bold}," `.

Comment: yeah, this method works for anything.  It worked for the tics also.